# Returning many columns in a function call

Tags: php, mysql

Although it works fine, *I want to learn* (I read on web and looked for examples but couldn't find anything) if what I ask below possible. As you can see in my function, I concatenate 3 columns to return as one single string and explode it in my PHP code to use them.

Can I return those 3 columns individually in one go without using `CONCAT_WS()` and not use `explode` in PHP?

Thanks

**MY MYSQL FUNCTION:**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS function_institute_university;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION function_institute_university (IN_partnership_id INTEGER(11))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
    DECLARE InsCode_UniID_UniCode VARCHAR(250);

    SELECT
        CONCAT_WS('~',
            UPPER(institute.Code),
            university.id,
            UPPER(university.UnivAcronym)
        ) INTO InsCode_UniID_UniCode
    FROM partnership
    LEFT JOIN institute ON institute.id = partnership.iid
    LEFT JOIN university ON university.id = partnership.uid
    WHERE
        partnership.id = IN_partnership_id AND
        partnership.active = '1'
      LIMIT 1;

    RETURN InsCode_UniID_UniCode;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**MY PHP CODE:**

```
$sql = "SELECT function_institute_university(15)";
$runSql = mysql_query($sql);

if(@mysql_num_rows($runSql) == 1)
{
   $newArray = mysql_fetch_array($runSql);
   list($instituteCode, $universityID, $universityCode) = explode('~', $newArray[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: After second look I see that you're using a function(completely overlooked) which returns only one value , can you change it to procedure instead?

SQL:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_institute_university;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_institute_university (IN_partnership_id INTEGER(11))
BEGIN
    SELECT
        UPPER(institute.Code) as `institiute_code`,
        university.id as `university_id`,
        UPPER(university.UnivAcronym) as `university_acronym`
    FROM partnership
    LEFT JOIN institute ON institute.id = partnership.iid
    LEFT JOIN university ON university.id = partnership.uid
    WHERE
        partnership.id = IN_partnership_id AND
        partnership.active = '1'
      LIMIT 1;
END$$
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "call procedure_institute_university(15)";
$runSql = mysql_query($sql);

if(@mysql_num_rows($runSql) == 1)
{
   $newArray = mysql_fetch_array($runSql);
   list($instituteCode, $universityID, $universityCode) = $newArray[0]['institute_code'], $newArray[0]['university_id'], $newArray[0]['university_acronym'];
}
```

Added alias so that you can be certain what is retrieved.  You could also use `mysql_fetch_assoc`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead to get associative array.  Please read the warning message in that page when you read the docs.

Comment: If not possible with function then I'll have to use procedures so it is acceptable by me. Thank you.